# value passed from datagridview to another form just showing the first value in the gridview not value of the unque row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to pass the value of a datagridview to another for, that means when I click on the button on the datagridview it should determine the row which was click and transfer the data of that row to the new form, the problem here is that the code detects the row which was clicked but when transferring the data to the new form, only the data of the very first row appear I have to navigate through it..

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
    'View Line Items buttons clicked
    'Get the ID of the selected invoice

    Dim i As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = MessageTBDataGridView.Rows(i)
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells(0)
    Dim MessageID As String = CStr(cell.Value)

    'Display the Line Items form
    Dim formthree As New Form3
    formthree.Tag = MessageID                   

    formthree.ShowDialog()
```

I want the data in the row which was clicked to be transfer to the new form any help pls

Comment: Please don't post code with fat wads of leading whitespace.  It just makes it harder to read.

Comment: Of course it only passes that one value.  That's all you are getting here: `Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells(0)`. If you want to pass all the data in the row to the other form then you need to get the data from the whole row, i.e. every cell in the row.

Comment: Ok thanks but how will I go about it

Comment: You obviously know how to get data from a cell, so you do that once for each cell in the row. You then combine that data in whatever way you decide is appropriate to pass to the other form.